# Is there any way to test the syntax of sql in NodeJS statically?

Tags: sql, node.js, jestjs

Is there any way to test the syntax of sql in **NodeJS** with **Jest**;

```
 const queryCurrencyCode = `
  SELECT USER_NAME FROM ${fromQueryUsers}
  WHERE USER_ID = '${userId}' AND HOBBY_ID = '${hobbyId}'
 ;`;
```